# Helmhotz decomposition and Regularity in Stokes equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

It is known that every function $f\in L^{q}(\Omega )^{n}$ can be uniquely
decomposed as 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\
f=f_{0}+\nabla Q,  \text{   (Helmhotz decomposition)}
\
\end{eqnarray*}  with $f_{0}\in L_{\sigma }^{q}(\Omega ),$ $Q\in L_{loc}^{q}(\Omega ),$ $%
\nabla Q\in \left( L^{q}(\Omega )\right) ^{n}$ and

\begin{eqnarray*} 
\
L_{\sigma }^{q}(\Omega ):=\overline{\left\{ v\in C_{0}^{\infty }(\Omega
)^{n}:\nabla\cdot v=0\right\} }^{L^{q}(\Omega )^{n}}.
\
\ 
\end{eqnarray*} 
 We define the natural projection $P_{q}:L^{q}\rightarrow L_{\sigma }^{q}$. Then we define the Stokes operator $
A_{q}=-P_{q}\Delta $ and also the space  $
\
D_{q}^{\alpha ,s}:=\left\{ v\in L_{\sigma }^{q}(\Omega ):\left\Vert
v\right\Vert _{D_{q}^{\alpha ,s}}:=\left\Vert v\right\Vert _{q}+\left(
\int_{0}^{\infty }\left\Vert t^{1-\alpha }A_{q}e^{-tA_{q}}v\right\Vert
_{q}^{s}\frac{dt}{t}\right) ^{1/s}<\infty \right\} .
\ $

My question is: Does anyone knows if I can assume  $
\
\left\{ v\in C_{0}^{\infty }(\Omega )^{n}:\nabla \cdot v=0\right\} \subset
D_{q}^{\alpha ,s}?
\ $
If not, I would like to know if there is some set of smooth functions that
is contained in $D_{q}^{\alpha ,s}.$

Additional information: Let me say a couple of words about the context of my
question. I am working with the stokes equation:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}-\Delta \mathbf{u}+\nabla P &=&f, \\ \nabla \cdot\mathbf{u}=0, \text{ in }\Omega \times (0,T)
 \\ \mathbf{u} &=&0\text{ on }\partial \Omega ,\mathbf{u}(x,0)=%
\mathbf{u}_{0},
\end{eqnarray*}
A theorem from Giga&Sohr (Th. 4.3, L^{p} estimates for the Cauchy problem with applications to the Navier-Stokes equations in exterior domains, 1991, 72-94.) says that there are solutions satisfying:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\
\int_{0}^{T}\left\Vert \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}(t)\right\Vert
_{r}^{p}dt+\int_{0}^{T}\left\Vert \nabla ^{2}\mathbf{u}(t)\right\Vert
_{r}^{p}dt+\int_{0}^{T}\left\Vert \nabla P\right\Vert _{r}^{p}dt\leq C\left(
\int_{0}^{T}\left\Vert f(t)\right\Vert _{r}^{p}dt+\left\Vert \mathbf{u}%
_{0}\right\Vert _{D_{r}^{1-1/p,p}}\right) .
\
\end{eqnarray*}
I am using this this theorem several times in a proof, but I am changing time and again the parameters $p$
and $r$ in $\left\Vert \mathbf{u}_{0}\right\Vert _{D_{r}^{1-1/p,p}}.$
Therefore I would like just to say that the initial data satisfies
\begin{eqnarray*}
\
\mathbf{u}_{0}\in \left\{ v\in C_{0}^{\infty }(\Omega )^{n}:\nabla\cdot
v=0\right\} 
\end{eqnarray*} and hence forget the problem with the parameters.

Comment: Are you aware of the paper of [Amrouche and Seloula](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218202512500455) on the $L^p$ theory for Stokes?